# Java object assignment confusion

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage

I saw this code while watching a video, and I'm not really sure why it works.

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

and if you change the data in the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
    pixels[i] = 0xff0000;
}
```

the image changes too. Can someone explain why this is? I thought the first assignment would set the array to the image data, but the assignment in the for loop would make the array unrelated to the image. Why does changing the values in the array change the data in the image?

Complete example:

```
public class Test extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BufferedImage image;
    private int[] pixels;

    public Test() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        image = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[i] = 0xff0000;
        }
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        Test test = new Test();
        frame.getContentPane().add(test);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
I have since solved my issue, but to clarify what I was asking for anyone who might stumble onto this, my question was about assignments in Java. I didn't realize that variables were given memory addresses, rather than copies of objects, when assigning. Consequently, when a variable is assigned to an object, if the variable changes, so will the original object (at least I think that's what is being said, please correct me if I'm wrong). Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: `image` and `pixels` are object members and you create them in the constructor `Test()`. They are *cached* and the same data in your loop. The loop over `pixels` is writing exactly into the pixel array of your image, that you are drawing in the `paintComponent()`method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in java, you don't store objects inside fields and variables, you store a memory address (kinda like pointers in c++ (Note: they are literally pointers, this is why the exception is called Null**Pointer**Exception)). When you copy a variable, then instead of getting a new object, you get the same memory address to the same object, so if you edit that object, you only edit the one stored in the memory.